# How a user can have multiple likes?

Tags: php, mysql

Well lately I'm making a script application. People can post and share stuff (let's call them object for the purpose of the question). Thing is, that a user can "bookmark an object" in his profile.

I have a table for users with unique uid (primary key) and a table for objects with a unique oid (primary key). I was thinking of making a new table in MySQL, calling it liked_objects which will have the following:

id - oid - uid

Each time I need to find all the object that user X liked I may run a query

`SELECT * FROM liked_objects WHERE uid = userXid`

My question is: Is there a most efficient way of doing this?

I'm using PHP 5 and MySQL Database.
Best regards

Comment: That looks fine. What kind of problem are you actually facing?

Comment: No problem actually. I just needed to know if this is efficient...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an id column for your `liked_objects` table. Assuming a user can only like each object once, you can just use two columns:

`uid | oid`

Make the Primary Key be both columns. Then to unlike an object you just:

`` DELETE FROM `liked_objects` WHERE uid = 'user_id' AND oid = 'object_id' ``

To like an object you:

`` INSERT INTO `liked_objects` (`uid`, `oid`) VALUES('user_id', 'object_id') ``

And you can select the liked objects the way you said.

Comment: Well yeah, I'd do the same, but maybe I need to track the time the "like" happened, so that's why I've put the id. Anyhow, is this efficient? As far as the speed/performance?

Comment: You still don't need an id, you can just add a third column then called `time` which isn't part of the key. Yes this is efficient. You might be able to get a small gain by adding another index on the uid column alone, but I don't think you'll get much of a gain from that. Is your database going to have millions of rows?

Comment: Hypothetically it could have as much object as I need and as much users as I need. So that makes my liked_objects table grow fast. Well, not a million but it should have many records... I still think I won't have any problem, but what else could you propose?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's as efficient as you're going to get, just make sure your `uid` column in `liked_objects` is indexed to help speed up your queries.

Comment: Indexed? Could you be more specific?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to [read this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html), I'd mostly be regurgitating that anyway! Also the [CREATE INDEX syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) will help you

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many times you're running that query. It doesn't get much simpler than that, but if you need to optimize things you could always cache the liked objects or even grab them in a join when you select the rest of the user information.

Comment: I'm gonna run the query each time a user looks his profile. Is it good to run this query..?

Comment: [Premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization) and all...

Comment: @JaredFarrish, have you ever worked on enterprise-level projects? "Premature" optimization saves hundreds of hours of troubleshooting and debugging bottlenecks. Get in the habit of optimizing as you go instead of writing junk code in haste to meet deadlines, and see how your opinions will change against Mr. Kunth.

Comment: And you know that this is that kind of project because...?

Comment: I don't, but a habit is a habit and good habits are just as hard to break as bad ones.

Comment: seems like I do have much reading here... thanks for helping me anyway :)

Comment: "Enterprise-level" notwithstanding, I can understand simple optimizations due to everyday procedural bottlenecks. You miss the point of the "premature optimization" comment.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, your proposed solution is exactly how you want to do it. Just make sure to add indexes on your new table to significantly speed that query.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the field "id" and take "oid" and "uid" as a compound primary key.

Answer (score 0):

i personally recommends you use your current idea. else

another approach :

**Serialize**

Serialize function help you store arrays into mysql field

use help of serialize function to story array of users that did like these objects to a field (**users_liked.objects**) on objects table.

and another array stored to user field with the objects that he did likes. (**likes.users**)

Pros:

When Showing object. just get users_liked.obj

When showing users likes.get likes.user

cons: when user likes, you have to add his id to users_liked.objects and object ID to likes.users

Comment: My concern is performance. What would be more efficient? Thanks for giving me this alternative :)

Comment: well with serialize you will only send one query to get the object details including the Likes. so there will be no other table.